# python regex not capturing variables, but regex working

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I am trying to create a data frame with variables: `bidder_rank, bidder_id, bid_total, bidder_info`. I have created a regex pattern, which seems to work on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/GzCQk8/1). However, the Python script has been breaking for a reason I cannot figure out.

```
# imports
import os
import pandas as pd
import re

# text
texty = '''

1            A)     $11,644,939.00    VC0000007181  S.T. RHOADES CONSTRUCTION, INC.                        Phone  (530)223-9322

             B)     210 Days * 10000                8585 COMMERCIAL WAY                                    CSLB#  00930684

             A+B)   $13,744,939.00                  REDDING CA     96002

2            A)     $12,561,053.00    VC0000007021  GR SUNDBERG, INC.                                      Phone  (707)825-6565

             B)     210 Days * 10000                5211 BOYD ROAD                                         CSLB#  00732695

             A+B)   $14,661,053.00                  ARCATA CA      95521                                   Fax    (707)825-6563

3            A)     $13,098,288.00    VC1800001127  CALIFORNIA HIGHWAY CONSTRUCTION GROUP,                 Phone  (925)766-7014

                                                    INC.

             B)     210 Days * 10000                1647 WILLOW PASS ROAD                                  CSLB#  01027700

             A+B)   $15,198,288.00                  CONCORD CA     94520                                   Fax    (925)265-9101

4            A)     $13,661,954.26    VC0000003985  MERCER FRASER COMPANY                                  Phone  (707)443-6371

             B)     210 Days * 10000                200 DINSMORE DR                                        CSLB#  00105709

             A+B)   $15,761,954.26                  FORTUNA CA     95540                                   Fax    (707)443-0277

Bid Opening Date: 11/15/2022                                                                          Page 2

Contract Number:  01-0H20U4                                                                           11/15/2022

5  A)             $15,396,278.00    VC0000000213  GRANITE CONSTRUCTION COMPANY  Phone  (831)728-7561

   B)             210 Days * 10000                585 W BEACH STREET            CSLB#  00000089

   A+B)           $17,496,278.00                  WATSONVILLE CA  95076

Bid Opening Date:  11/15/2022                                                                                                  Page 3

Contract Number:   01-0H20U4                                                                                                   11/15/2022

                                                          '''

lines = re.split(r'(?=^\d)', texty, flags=re.MULTILINE)

# list of bids
bids = []

# loop through each line in the bid rank bid ID data table
for i in (0, len(lines)-1):

    l = lines[i]
    ok = re.findall(r"(?ms)(^\d+)\s*(.*)(VC\d+)\s+(.*)([\s\S]*?)(A\+B\)\s+(\$\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?))", str(l))

    # continue if ok is not empty

    if len(ok) == 0:
        continue

    else:
        ok = ok[0]

    # first group is bid_rank, third group is bid_id, fourth group is bidder_info, seventh group is bid_total
    bidder_rank = ok[0]
    bidder_id = ok[2]
    bidder_info = ok[3]
    bid_total = ok[6]

    # create a tuple of the bid rank, bid ID, bidder info, and bid total
    bid_tuple = (bidder_rank, bidder_id, bidder_info, bid_total)

    # append the tuple to the list of bids
    bids.append(bid_tuple)

    print(bid_tuple)

# create a dataframe of the bids
biddf = pd.DataFrame(bids, columns=['bidder_rank', 'bidder_id', 'bidder_info', 'bid_total'])

print(biddf)
```

After digging, it seems that it's only working for bidder_id = 5.

```
>>> print(biddf)
  bidder_rank     bidder_id                                        bidder_info       bid_total
0           5  VC0000000213  GRANITE CONSTRUCTION COMPANY  Phone  (831)728-...  $17,496,278.00
```

But, according to regex101, it should work for all the bidder IDs. Am I missing something?

Comment: When you're testing on regex101, you should remember to select Python from the FLAVOR menu on the left. It doesn't seem to make a difference in this case, but it might have.

Comment: Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):`. Use `for item in list:` or `for index, item in enumerate(list):`

Comment: If you're only interested in the first match, use `re.search()` rather than `re.findall()`.

Comment: It doesn't work in regex101 when I enable the `s` flag like you have in your regexp.

Comment: There's no need to use `str(l)` since `l` is a string.

Comment: The name of the variable is `text`, but you're using `texty` in your `re.split()` call. Is that a copying error or in the real code?

Comment: @Barmar - thank you so much! and the text string is actually `texty` in the actual code.

Comment: So should it be `texty = '''`? Please edit the question to show the correct code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex works fine for me, as long as you don't use the `s` flag. I have modified it slightly to remove unnecessary capture groups and change required groups to non-capturing groups to remove them from the output.

```
(^\d+)\s*.*?(VC\d+)\s+(.*)(?:[\s\S]*?)A\+B\)\s+(\$\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?)
```

[Regex demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iJ66fW/1)

You can then apply `re.findall` to the entire text and use that output directly in a call to `pd.DataFrame`:

```py
biddf = pd.DataFrame(
    re.findall(r'(?m)(^\d+)\s*.*?(VC\d+)\s+(.*)(?:[\s\S]*?)A\+B\)\s+(\$\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?)', text),
    columns=['bidder_rank', 'bidder_id', 'bidder_info', 'bid_total']
)
```

Output:

```
  bidder_rank     bidder_id                                        bidder_info       bid_total
0           1  VC0000007181  S.T. RHOADES CONSTRUCTION, INC.               ...  $13,744,939.00
1           2  VC0000007021  GR SUNDBERG, INC.                             ...  $14,661,053.00
2           3  VC1800001127  CALIFORNIA HIGHWAY CONSTRUCTION GROUP,        ...  $15,198,288.00
3           4  VC0000003985  MERCER FRASER COMPANY                         ...  $15,761,954.26
4           5  VC0000000213  GRANITE CONSTRUCTION COMPANY  Phone  (831)728-...  $17,496,278.00
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a few things we have to change in your code, first in your for loop, you are iterating over a tuple `(0, len(lines)-1)`, which means it only checks for the first and last items in lines, then your regex pattern is too complicated, also you do not split your input string into lines in the proper way.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

text = '''...'''  # Your input text here

lines = text.splitlines()

bids = []

pattern = r"(?ms)^\s*(\d+)\s+A\)\s+(\$\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?)\s+(VC\d+)\s+([^\n]+)"

for i in range(len(lines)):
    l = lines[i]
    ok = re.findall(pattern, str(l))
    if len(ok) == 0:
        continue
    else:
        ok = ok[0]

    bidder_rank = ok[0]
    bidder_id = ok[3]
    bidder_info = ok[4]
    bid_total = ok[1]

    bid_tuple = (bidder_rank, bidder_id, bidder_info, bid_total)

    bids.append(bid_tuple)

    print(bid_tuple)

biddf = pd.DataFrame(bids, columns=['bidder_rank', 'bidder_id', 'bidder_info', 'bid_total'])

print(biddf)
```

Comment: He's not splitting into lines because the pattern is spread over multiple lines. Each "line" is the group of lines starting with a a number 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

Comment: Don't use `for i in range` use `for l in lines:`